# Reading a local file into a ShinyApp hosted on server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a `shiny` app hosted on a server, and part of its functionality is to read local files. I realise there is the very helpful `fileIput` function in `shiny` package - and I may use it instead - but for now I would like to learn about using file paths. The problem I face follows:

I am using the `tm` package, which allows users to read text files either from a directory (using `DirSource("filePath")`)or using inidividual files (using `VectorSource("filePath")`).

```
initialCorpus<- reactive({
            if(input$confirm==0)
            return()
            isolate({
                if(input$corpusType=="dir"){
                    myPath<- input$filePath
                    myCorpus<- Corpus(DirSource(myPath))
                    myCorpus
                    }
                else if(input$corpusType=="vector"){
                    myPath<- input$filePath
                    myFile<- scan(file=myPath,what="character",n=-1, sep="\n")
                    myCorpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(myFile))
                    myCorpus
                    } 
...
```

The same function works fine and reads in text files when I am using my `shiny` app locally. However, when I upload my app to `shinyapp`, and then try to upload a local file, I am unable to read in files.

So, why is it not possible to read in local files by shinyApp when the file path is used? It may be a basic question, but I want to learn.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I would be happy to link to my application if required, it's just that I would like to show my application when it's properly functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem by isolating the part where you source your files : `isolate({DirSource("filePath")})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked. I have it the same way as you wrote: `isolate({ if(input$corpusType=="dir"){ myPath<- input$filePath myCorpus<- Corpus(DirSource(myPath)) myCorpus }`